# There's a way of applying a laravel filter for HTTP method? Like on POST?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I develop a system using `laravel`, and my system has a kind of user how can do some special operations, called MASTER.

He is the only one kind of user how can Create/Edit things. The users with "READ" permissions can read then (Show method), though.

There's an way of applying a filter for the post methods?

NOTE: I use `laravel "Route::resource"`, so grouping them and apllying a filter, dispite the fact that is more logical and easy, is it not a easy task to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register filters directly in the controller as [documented here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#controller-filters)

This would be for all POST requests:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('permission', array('on' => 'post'));
}
```

Or for some specific controller methods:

```
$this->beforeFilter('permission', array('only' => array('create', 'edit', 'store', 'update', 'delete'));
```

However in this scenario the simplest thing might be to just specify the methods that are allowed for everyone to call:

```
$this->beforeFilter('permission', array('except' => array('index', 'show')));
```